# CollectionChanged not firing when Inserting Items to Trackable Collection

Tags: c#, proxy, change-tracking

Using [ChangeTracking](https://github.com/joelweiss/ChangeTracking) Library, When Add an Item with Add method the CollectionChanged is called, but when Add an item to the Collection using Insert method the CollectionChanged  never called !

```
var order = new Order
{
    Id = 1,
    CustomerNumber = "Test",
    Address = new Address
    {
        AddressId = 1,
        City = "New York"
    },
    OrderDetails = new ObservableCollection<OrderDetail>
    {
        new OrderDetail
        {
            OrderDetailId = 1,
            ItemNo = "Item123"
        },
        new OrderDetail
        {
            OrderDetailId = 2,
            ItemNo = "Item369"
        }
    }
};

TrackableOrder = order.AsTrackable();

((INotifyCollectionChanged)TrackableOrder.OrderDetails).CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //called on add but not On Insert
}
```

**Adding items with Insert OnCollectionChanged never called thus the UI will not be notified**

```
TrackableOrder.OrderDetails.Insert(0, new OrderDetail()
{
    ItemNo = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}",
    OrderDetailId = 100
});
```

**Adding items with Add OnCollectionChanged called**

```
TrackableOrder.OrderDetails.Add(new OrderDetail()
{
    ItemNo = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}",
    OrderDetailId = 200
});
```

**Any help will be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

it was a bug in the library and it fixed, 
**Child collection skiping insert + more methods :** 
https://github.com/joelweiss/ChangeTracking/pull/44